# AVAudioPlayer playback stops when new NSView is added

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avaudioplayer, nsviewcontroller

I have AVAudioPlayer instance playing music.  The instance is in the controller for the main view on my main window - it isn't very fancy, but it works:

in the .h

```
@interface ViewController () {
    AVAudioPlayer *music;
}
@end
```

in the .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    music = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/music01.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]] error:nil];
    [music playAtTime:0]; // play from start
    [music prepareToPlay];
}

-(void)playMusic {
    if (music) {
        [music play];
    }
}
```

So far so good.  Except that if I add a view (programatically, with it's own NSViewController) to the main view the music stops.  Suddenly.  Is this normal?  What have I done wrong?

Comment: It is impossible to tell with the given lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is that you somehow call stop on your `AVAudioPlayer` instance when that view gets added to the window. There are many ways in which you can debug this, but, I'd put a symbolic breakpoint (you can read more about this kind of breakpoints here on SO) in the `stop` method and see if it gets called and from where. Also, check if you don't call `viewDidLoad` again when you add a new view (due to the inheritance you might have in place)

Otherwise, there's no way adding a view might trigger a system issue that might stop your instance.